# Empty Class and List Paradoxes?

Tags: java

If I create a class with nothing in it and then instantiate it `n` times, is it possible for an `OutOfMemory` error to occur?

If I create a class and inside that class' constructor create an instance of itself, will I have an infinite nesting of the same class? Will an `OutOfMemory` error occur?

Suppose I created a class which is supposed to get fed objects and check if they have any variable references to themselves, and include them in a list if they do not. How will my class react when the object passed to it is itself?

I'm mostly interested in how this applies to Java, as opposed to C`x` , but still it would be interesting to note if they might behave differently.

Comment: Why not simply try these things and find out?

Comment: Mostly because I assume I would have to wait for days for an out of memory error to occur if it would, as 4 gigabytes of memory should hold at minimum an extremely large number of empty references

Comment: That would be a bad assumption. Which is why, in general, you don't make assumptions in engineering.

Comment: @ACArcana: Firstly: it's unlikely that your JVM is configured to use up 4 GB of memory; and if it *is*, then it's most likely because you've done that intentionally, in which case you must know how to change it. Secondly: if you're just doing this in an infinite loop, then you can go through a lot of memory very quickly. Try it and see!

Comment: @ACArcana probably more like a few seconds (at most)...

Comment: Java doesn't have such a thing as an empty class because all classes must derive from Object.

Comment: This intrigues me. Is there somewhere I can see how Object itself is actually defined? Do all class actually contain a hidden instance of Object, or are they somehow extending it automatically?

Comment: @ACArcana - we're into "Read the tutorials or a beginner's book" territory now. Everything aside from primitives in Java are objects on the heap, and all objects extend `Object`

Comment: I've read those books but by now long forgotten the implementation of things like that. Now that I'm at a point where I'm actually interested in knowing this and truly understanding how that works, it is more interesting to me. Put simply, it did not interest me to know that a class extends object, when I didn't know what extend even meant. Still, I appreciate your answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I create a class with nothing in it and then instantiate it n times, is it possible for an OutOfMemory error to occur?

Yes.  If N is large enough.

> If I create a class and inside that class' constructor create an instance of itself, will I have an infinite nesting of the same class?

If you had an infinite amount of memory, yes.  In practice you don't, so the creation is bound to fail.

> Will an OutOfMemory error occur?

Possibly.  It is more likely that you will get a StackOverflow error ... because what you are describing will create a recursion loop.

> Suppose I created a class which is supposed to get fed objects and check if they have any variable references to themselves, and include them in a list if they do not. How will my class react when the object passed to it is itself?

It is impossible to say.  It depends on *how* you implement the code to "check if they have any variable references to themselves".

---

You seem to be trying to explore the consequences of Russell's Paradox for Java programs.  The simple answer is that it has no consequences.  A Java program that involves representations of sets will do whatever it has been coded to do.  If you have a representation that allows a "set" to "contain" itself, then that will happen.

There is one thing that should be obvious though.  A simple representation of sets in Java will not allow you to represent sets with infinite numbers of elements.  Memory (and stacks) in Java are finite.  This doesn't mean that it is impossible to represent all infinite sets.  You just have to do it differently; e.g. using "lazy" data structures or a symbolic representation.

---

It is tempting to think that a representation of sets might actually *be* mathematical sets, and you might be able to cause unspecified weirdness by triggering Russell's paradox.  In reality, no such thing will happen.  Russell's paradox asks the question "Does the set of all sets contain itself?".  But a program on a Turing-machine-equivalent computer cannot test all elements in a simple infinite set ... let alone the set of all sets.  Russell's question is simply not a tractable problem.  (But then, it was never *intended* to be tractable.  It is really about exploring the limits of *meaningful mathematics*.)

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. You're right that Russell's Paradox did spark these questions. However, I did not assume that Java would in itself truly contain paradoxes. I was moreso interested in how Java and Sun have chosen to handle those types of issues, and how the language and VM are intended to handle such happenstances.

Comment: @ACArcana - Java does not contain paradoxes like this.  It does however have limits ... and you have to stay within those limits, or bad things happen.  Other examples of these limits are that the primitive numeric types only represent a finite subset of the corresponding infinite mathematical domains (integers and reals), and that array sizes are limited.

Comment: I wasn't even aware that there was actually a preset limit aside from memory for the size of Arrays. I just looked it up and indeed found it interesting as well. I find this all intriguing because with finite resources in some ways the Java language still attempts to define infinity (ie. `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`) and I'm intrigued in how to solve the many problems this presents (which obviously Sun has addressed). For example I'm intrigued if it is even possible to check programatically if two posited infinite sets have a 1 to 1 ratio.

Comment: @ACArcana - 1) Java uses standard IEE floating point representations.  The range / precision limits are inherent in the representation.  2) That computation would be infinite, so you would need to do it by some kind of symbolic reasoning.  That is out-of-scope for conventional programming languages.  It is not the kind of problem that PL's are designed to handle.  You would need to do that at the application programming level; i.e. by implementing a symbolic reasoning engine.

Comment: This intrigued me enough to attempt to find a reasoning engine I could dissect. In case you or anyone is also interested an Open Source Inference Engine called OpenCyc can be found here: http://www.opencyc.org/cb/welcome .

Comment: Is there any way to get Java to nest variables repeatedly when a variable reaches its maximum value? For example when an integer reaches maximum create a list of integers and sum them. When the list reaches its maximum size create a list containing this list and continue to make new lists. I can picture programming to a specific level, but I can't fathom how to ask Java to keep repeating the process when the lists hit maximum size.

Comment: No there isn't.  But you could look at the `BigInteger` class.  For lists, the `ArrayList` is limited to `2^31 - 1` elements, but a `LinkedList` is only limited by the amount of memory you have available.

Comment: So a LinkedList actually solves that in a sense anyway. I'll look up the implementation of BigInteger and LinkedList. Thanks for all the info, I've learned a lot and have much more researching to do. rep += Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY to you, good sir.